# Missing punctuation from C++ hex2bin

Tags: c++, string, hex, binary-data, printf

While trying to duplicate PHP's `bin2hex($s)` and `pack('H*',$s)` (aka `hex2bin($s)` in PHP 5.4.3+) in GCC/Linux C++, I seem to have it figured out except that it's dropping punctuation for some strange reason. Can you figure out what I might be doing wrong in the hex2bin() function? I compared PHP's bin2hex() with mine and it appears to be working there properly, so the problem is in hex2bin().

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

string bin2hex(string s) {
  int nLen = s.length();
  string sOut;
  char cBuff[2];
  for (int i = 0; i < nLen; i++) {
    sprintf(cBuff,"%.2x",s[i]);
    sOut.append(cBuff);
    cBuff[0] = '\0';
  }
  return sOut;
}

string hex2bin(string s) {
  int nLen = s.length();
  string sOut;
  char cBuff1[2];
  char cBuff2[2];
  char cBuff[1];
  int n,n1,n2;
  for (int i = 0; i <= nLen; i+=2) {
    sprintf(cBuff1,"%c",s[i]);
    sprintf(cBuff2,"%c",s[i+1]);
    n1 = atoi(cBuff1);
    n2 = atoi(cBuff2);
    n = (n1 * 16) + n2;
    sprintf(cBuff,"%c",n);
    sOut.append(cBuff);
    cBuff[0] = '\0';
    cBuff1[0] = '\0';
    cBuff2[0] = '\0';
  }
  return sOut;
}

int main() {
  string s;
  string sResult;  
  s = "This is a 123 test.";
  sResult = bin2hex(s);
  printf("ENCODED: %s\n",sResult.c_str());
  sResult = hex2bin(sResult);
  printf("UNENCODED: %s\n",sResult.c_str());
  return 1;
}
```

This emits:

```
ENCODED: 5468697320697320612031323320746573742e
UNENCODED: This is a 123 test
```

Comment: That's... pretty disturbing code. Also: hex is _encoding_ ***not*** _encryption_. I hope you know the difference. (!?!?). (I've taken the liberty to rewrite this into a C++ implementation. See my answer)

Comment: What did you expect n2 = atoi(cBuff2); to do when it got to that "e" at the end of your input?  It will return 0 and n will be 2*16+0 = 32 which is a space.  I don't think you can use atoi - you need something that can accept a radix af 16.  strtol would probably work.  And possibly sscanf.

Comment: @sehe Look me up on Twitter and let's connect on email. I am revisiting C++ after not touching it for 20 years. Your feedback is warranted, and any detailed feedback on how I can code better on that platform is appreciated. For instance, I didn't even focus on memory leaks because I don't know how to properly deallocate stuff.

Comment: @sehe By the way, this piece was used as a portion of some cross-platform encryption I'm working on, and I forgot to change the function names to reflect that you are correct, it is encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, sleeves rolled up: let's look at C++ version:

**[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/551344666eb260af)**

- Don't use C strings unless you need to (sprintf to build a two-char string is not... very efficient)
- Use iostreams to encode/decode the hex digits (`std::hex`)
- The `hex2bin` could optimized, but I went for "simpler"
- I added a *modicum* of input sanitizing on `hex2bin`

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string bin2hex(std::string const &s) {
    std::ostringstream oss;

    for (unsigned char ch : s)
        oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int) ch;

    return oss.str();
}

#include <cassert>
std::string hex2bin(std::string const& s) {
    assert(s.length() % 2 == 0);

    std::string sOut;
    sOut.reserve(s.length()/2);

    std::string extract;
    for (std::string::const_iterator pos = s.begin(); pos<s.end(); pos += 2)
    {
        extract.assign(pos, pos+2);
        sOut.push_back(std::stoi(extract, nullptr, 16));
    }
    return sOut;
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "ENCODED: " << bin2hex("This is a 123 test.")          << "\n";
    std::cout << "DECODED: " << hex2bin(bin2hex("This is a 123 test.")) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ENCODED: 5468697320697320612031323320746573742e
DECODED: This is a 123 test.
```

Comment: further improved, to use `std::stoi` instead of `istringstream` in `hex2bin`

Comment: My G++ gives me an error on the for auto line in bin2hex. It says: `error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token`

Comment: I switched the for in bin2hex to `for (int i=0;i<nLen;i++)` and then switched the `(int) ch` in bin2hex to `(int) s[i]` and got the coding working with your help. My compiler is too old.

Comment: I wish I knew what includes one needs in order to compile. I had to do trial/error until I found it. Also, I need to learn a whole lot more about the `<<` and `>>` operators as well as things like `ostringstream`, `istringstream`, `hex`, and `setw(2)`.

Comment: @Volomike erm. Seems I forgot the include for `printf`. See my edit :)

Comment: ERROR: bin2hex() will return the wrong value for any char above 128.. to fix it, change `for (auto ch : s)` to `for (unsigned char ch : s)` (i have verified that with the unsigned fix, it return the correct value for every char between 0x00 - 0xFF)

Comment: @hanshenrik excellent spot. Fixed (Somewhere in the past I have have started using `unsigned char` for anything that deals with characters as ordinals (including everything from `<cctype>`) but apparently not at the timw I wrote this answer). Technically, the behaviour was implementation dependent, but that doesn't help if your implementation has `signed` `char` by default.

Answer (score 3):

With all but the period `'.'` you just went lucky: the hex digits didn't use an actual hexadecimal value. However, for the period you got `2e` but you tried to decode the `e` using `atoi("e")`, roughly: that won't work as `atoi()` requires a decimal value. You could use `strtol(str, 0, 16)` instead to decode the hexadecimal value.

Note that you have a few buffer overruns when you are using `sprintf()`: this function writes a terminating null character. In general, you are much better off to `snprintf()` to avoid buffer overruns. Also, in your decoding routine you access values beyond the end of your string (you use `i <= nLen` with `nLen = s.length()` and then access `s[i]` and `s[i+1]`). Of course, the code is far too complex:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string bin2hex(std::string s) {
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for (char c: s) {
        out << std::setw(2) << int(c);
    }
    return out.str();
}

std::string hex2bin(std::string s) {
    std::string rc;
    int nLen = s.length();
    int tmp;
    for (int i(0); i + 1 < nLen; i += 2) {
        if (std::istringstream(s.substr(i, 2)) >> std::hex >> tmp) {
            rc.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }
    return rc;
}

int main() {
  std::string s;
  std::string sResult;  
  s = "This is a 123 test.";
  sResult = bin2hex(s);
  std::cout << "ENCRYPTED: " << sResult << '\n';
  sResult = hex2bin(sResult);
  std::cout << "UNENCRYPTED: " << sResult << '\n';
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: O hey, +1, another faithful iostreams offering. I'm a bit disappointed you left the misnomers `ENCRYPTED` and `UNENCRYPTED` (_sic_) in though :/

Comment: ERROR: bin2hex() will return the wrong value for any character above 128... to fix it, change `for (char c: s) {`  to `for (unsigned char c: s) {` - (i have verified that with the unsigned fix, it return the correct value for every char between 0x00 - 0xFF)

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not convert hexadecimal digits correctly because atoi can only handle decimal digits. Try this

```
sprintf(cBuff1,"%c",s[i]);
sprintf(cBuff2,"%c",s[i+1]);
n1 = strtoul(cBuff1, 0, 16);
n2 = strtoul(cBuff2, 0, 16);
```

Also your for loop should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < nLen; i+=2) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n1 = atoi(cBuff1);
n2 = atoi(cBuff2);
n = (n1 * 16) + n2;
```

if `cbuff1` is, say, `"a"`, then this won't work, since `a` is not a digit. It works fine for digits that are '0-9', but not 'a-f'.

You will need to translate non-digits to numeric values.

There are quite a few ways to convert a hex value string to a byte. I think this is pretty decent:

```
int hexchar(char c)
{
   if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return c - '0';
   // if you need to support upper-case hex:
   // c = tolower(c); 
   if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') return c - 'a' + 10; 
   // If we get here, panic
   cout << "Error, invalid hex digit:" << c << endl;
   return -1;
}

int hexbyte(string s)
{
    for(i = 0; i < s.length(); i+=2)
    {
       char c = hexbyte(s[i]);
       c <<= 4;
       c += hexbyte(s[i+1];
       cout << c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these trivial routines, good for C and C ++

```
/*------------------------------------------+
|       bin2hex     bin2hex     bin2hex     |
+------------------------------------------*/
static  char *bin2hex(unsigned char *s, long L)
{
    static  char hex[2048];
    long i,l=0;
    for (i=0; i<L; i++) l+=sprintf(&hex[l], "%02x", 0xFF & (*(s+i)));
    hex[l]=0;
    return hex;
}
/*------------------------------------------+
|       hex2bin     hex2bin     hex2bin     |
+------------------------------------------*/
static  char *hex2bin( char *s)
{
    static  char bin[2048];
    unsigned int i,e,l=0,L=strlen(s);
    for (i=0; i<L; i+=2) { sscanf(s+i, "%02x",&e); bin[l++]=(char)e; }
    bin[l]=0;
    return bin;
}
```

Comment: perhaps trivial, but thread-unsafe and will probably crash for inputs longer than 2048 =/