# How does C++ handle the bitshifting operators in this particular case?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

In [this question that I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18906027/105539), I received an answer that uses the bit shifting operators `<<` and `>>`. Can someone explain to me how this works? It appears to be translating, as if piping the value from one thing into the other all on one line in a series of left bit shift or right bit shift.

Please realize that I'm new to C++. I haven't studied it in 20 years, and I'm learning it again.

Comment: Do you mean things like `std::cout << "ENCRYPTED: " << sResult << '\n'`?

Comment: If this is a common misunderstanding, then why are people opting to close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [overloaded operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tk49fh2.aspx) they're not actually doing any bitshifting, your example seems to be using [ostream's << operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/) which inserts data into the output stream.

Answer (score 1):

here are some other topics on operation overloading
[Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)
Basically, any operator can be re-purposed for the use on other types, including non primitive types. In the example you listed, we would really have to know what types the << operator was being used on.  For streams, the << and >> operators have been overloaded to write content to the stream or read content from the stream.