# How to extract first 20 bits of Hexadecimal address?

Tags: hex, extract, 32-bit

I have the following *hexadecimal* 32 bit virtual address address: **0x274201**

> **How can I extract the *first 20 bits*, then convert them to decimal?**

I wanted to know how to do this by hand.

### Update:

> @Pete855217 pointed out that the address *0x274201* **is not** *32 bit*. 
>   Also **0x** is not part of the address as it is used to signify
>   a hexadecimal address.

Which suggests that I will add 00 after 0X, so now a true 32 bit address would be: **0x00274201**. I have updated my answer!

Comment: Do you have it as a String, as a number, and in what programming language?

Comment: I wanted to do this by hand. I apologize for not being so clear. I believe I have answered my own question and I hope I am correct?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906027/missing-punctuation-from-c-hex2bin. To do this by hand is relatively trivial, SO is not really a basic maths site, but there are numerous references to doing the conversions in a programming language around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have answered my own question and I hope I am correct?

> First convert HEX number **0x00274201** to *BIN (this is the long way but I learned something from this)*:

[image]

However, I noticed the first 20 bits include *00274* in HEX. Which makes sense because every HEX digit is four BIN digits.

So, since I wanted the first 20 bits, then I am really asking for the

> first ***five*** HEX digits because 5 * 4 = 20 (bits in BIN)

Thus this will yield **00274** in HEX = ***628*** in DEC (decimal).

Comment: The 32-bit number you are dealing with is 0027 4201. The 0x merely identifies it as hex, you don't convert those characters. The bits you want to get are from 27420, NOT 0x274 - that's only 12 bits, so you're answer is completely wrong.

Comment: No probs lucidgold, you're answer looks right to me ie. 0000 0000 0010 0111 0100