# Boost ASIO Serial Write Hex values

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio

I am communicating with a device via a serial port using ubuntu. All the messages need to be hex values. I have tested the communication setup using termite in a Windows environment and I get the responses I am expecting. I cannot get any responses when using Boost:asio though.

Here is how I am setting up my serial port:

```
boost::asio::serial_port serialPort;
    serialPort.open(portNumber);
    serialPort.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(baudRate));
    serialPort.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::character_size(8));
    serialPort.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(boost::asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one));
    serialPort.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity(boost::asio::serial_port_base::parity::none));
    serialPort.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control(boost::asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::none));

  uint8_t hexValue = message.at(i) >= 'A' ? (message.at(i) - 'A' + 10) : message.at(i) - '0';
  serialPort.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(&hexValue, sizeof(uint8_t)));
```

So is there something I need to setup in ASIO to make it send correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by "hex values"? Are you sure the line `uint8_t hexValue = ...;` is correct?

Comment: @MikeCAT I was looking to pass hex values like {0,1,...E,F} as binary data. So yeah it looks like my conversion was incorrect. However the person below who provided the a working conversion and way to write it to the serial port.

Comment: A byte (8 bits) is made of two hex digits,  not one. Are you sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like really you want to send the ***binary*** data that corresponds to the hex-encoded text you *have* in `message`.

There are many ways to skin that cat. I'd personally start with decoding the  whole message. This will always reduce the message from the hex-encoded size. So you can do this inplace, if you want.

A simple take from [an older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906027/missing-punctuation-from-c-hex2bin/18906270#18906270):

```
std::string hex2bin(std::string const& s) {
    assert(s.length() % 2 == 0);

    std::string sOut;
    sOut.reserve(s.length()/2);

    std::string extract;
    for (std::string::const_iterator pos = s.begin(); pos<s.end(); pos += 2)
    {
        extract.assign(pos, pos+2);
        sOut.push_back(std::stoi(extract, nullptr, 16));
    }
    return sOut;
}
```

Now you simply send the returned string to the serial port:

```
std::string binary_msg = hex2bin(message);
serialPort.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(binary_msg));
```

Also look at the global http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write.html to write the whole message in one composed operation.

Comment: can you explain what this function is doing exactly please?

Answer (score 0):

you seem to forgot the io_service for instanciate the serial_port. The serial_port default constructor has 2 parameters io_service and the port name